# C# Wpf create dynamic check boxes next to one another

Tags: c#, wpf

### **Problem**

I have a dynamic list of reports gathered from a database, and each of them will have the option to be exported in one of two formats, both, or neither. I would like this to be represented as a list of all reports with two adjacent checkboxes next to one one another (One checkbox for each report format) whose `IsEnabled` status will be predetermined.

### **My Current Solution**

**WPF**

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView Name="Views" Grid.Column ="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,3,30,0" Width="230" MaxHeight="300" Height="244" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="White">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" ></Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding OC}" >
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CheckedFormat1}" IsEnabled="{Binding EnabledFormat1}"  Click="CheckBoxStandardFormat1_Click" Loaded="CheckBoxStandardFormat1_Loaded" Margin="-20,0,0,0">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CheckedFormat2}" IsEnabled="{Binding EnabledFormat2}"   Click="CheckBoxStandardFormat2_Click" Loaded="CheckBoxStandardFormat2_Loaded" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  />
                </CheckBox>
                </CheckBox>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

`OC` is a data structure of reports which includes information on whether it is enabled for each report type. This code produced the following UI result:
[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04oVU.png)

However it looks like each instance within the `HeirachicalDataTemplate` is inheriting the status of `IsEnabled` from the previous ones, as the greyscale changes.

Does anyone have a better solution which will allow me to bind a dynamic list of reports to a WPF output, with the formatting as described above?

Sorry in advance if this is an easy question, I am really new to C#

**Update**

The following is a sample of my ViewModel

```
[PropertyChanged.AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class ReportsList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool CheckedFormat1 { get; set; }
    public bool CheckedFormat2 { get; set; }
    public bool EnabledFormat1 { get; set; }
    public bool EnabledFormat2 { get; set; }  

    public ReportsList()
    {
        EnabledFormat1 = true;
        EnabledFormat2 = true;
    }
}
```

and it's implementation as an `ObservableCollection`

```
public ObservableCollection<ReportsList> OC { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why would this be templated with a HierarchicalDataTemplate? It seems like it should be a listview or datagrid with a standard data template. I guess what I'm getting at is that a bit more context might be needed. What do the viewmodels look like?

Comment: Agree with Mike. And why are you nesting one checkbox inside the other? Use a container if you need to hold multiple controls. (e.g. `Grid`, `StackPanel`, `WrapPanel`, etc, etc)

Comment: Hi @mikez and the main reason I used this method was because every other method I tried ended up putting the check boxes one underneath the other. So it is not necessary for them to be nested, but it was the only solution I found online where they would be adjacent. I have included some more information for context. Hopefully there's an easy solution! thanks.

Comment: @Richardissimo I couldn't link you in the above comment, but answered your question in it too.

Comment: Hi @Richardissimo I have just added a bit more code for context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be no need to use a `TreeView` here. You just have a list of reports. Replace `TreeView` with `ListView` or `ItemsControl` and replace `HierarchicalDataTemplate` with `DataTemplate`. Rather than nesting the `CheckBox`es, use a `StackPanel` container to hold them together. And the margin of -20 wasn't helping. So you end up with:

```
    <ItemsControl Name="Views" Grid.Column ="0" ItemsSource="{Binding OC}" Margin="10,3,30,0" Width="230" MaxHeight="300" Height="244" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="White">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CheckedFormat1}" IsEnabled="{Binding EnabledFormat1}" Click="CheckBoxStandardFormat1_Click" Loaded="CheckBoxStandardFormat1_Loaded" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CheckedFormat2}" IsEnabled="{Binding EnabledFormat2}" Click="CheckBoxStandardFormat2_Click" Loaded="CheckBoxStandardFormat2_Loaded" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This compiles and runs, but it doesn't actually display any of the reports from the OC `ObservableCollection<ReportsList>`

Comment: Is the View's DataContext set to the ViewModel which contains your `OC` property, and does that contain any items? (because it works for me)

Comment: I just had to change the `ItemsSource` from `"{Binding OC}"` to  `"{Binding}"` and it works! Thanks, I knew there would be an easy solution :)

Comment: @WillM OK, that means you are using the View as the ViewModel, which is fine if that's what you want. It's more common to use MVVM, where the View and ViewModel are separate things. For example, `OC` would be on the ViewModel which is set as the DataContext for this View.